# Should I choose a short or lengthy title for my app on App Store?

Tags: ios, mobile-application, app, apple, optimisation

By now I have read numerous articles about App Store optimisation. Some advise me to use a long title with a lot of keywords (bang for my bucks etc…) but others say the title should be short (25 characters).

What should I choose? And why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Typically, the top performing apps have shorter (branded) titles

> [The average for the top 200 free apps are:](http://www.gummicube.com/blog/2015/04/app-title-length-and-aso/)
>
> 26 characters
> 4.5 words

#### But it probably doesn't matter

> App title length – if penalized at all by Apple, is easily offset by increased downloads or other variables weighted by Apple’s app store algorithm.
>
> It is up to the publisher/marketer to determine the best way to balance relevant target phrase coverage with the attractiveness of having  an app title that displays completely on all iOS devices.

There is some good [further analysis here](https://blog.appbot.co/tips-for-naming-your-mobile-app-or-game/) with a chart showing distribution of character length:

[image]